# What is the logic behind how bash tests for true/false?

Tags: bash

This:

```
$ echo $VAR
something
```

And this:

```
$ [[ -z "$VAR" ]]
$ echo $?
1
```

Yet this:

```
if [[ -z "$TMUX_MAN_PANE" ]]; then
   echo 'NEVER PRINTS!'
```

This screws with my head.

**UPDATE**

Here's some real code. I can't get this to work.

```
tmux_man_page() {
if [[ "$TERM" =~ 'screen' ]] && [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
  tmux list-panes -t $TMUX_MAN_PANE &> /dev/null
  echo $?
  echo $TMUX_MAN_PANE
  [[ -z "$TMUX_MAN_PANE" ]]
  echo $?
  if ! [[ -z "$TMUX_MAN_PANE" ]] && [[ $? ]]; then
    echo luck
    tmux -q respawn-pane -k -t $TMUX_MAN_PANE man $1
  else
    echo fuck
    tmux split-window -vf man $1
    TMUX_MAN_PANE=$(tmux display-message -p "#{pane_id}")
    export TMUX_MAN_PANE
    tmux select-pane -t {last}
  fi
fi
}
```

**UPDATE 2: Success**

Finally figured it out. Was having problems getting the status of the first line in the if statement. Had to do some trickery to get the output of the tmux statement in the first line of the if statement. If anyone knows a cleaner way to do this, I'm all ears.

Here's the working code:

```
tmux_man_page() {
if [[ "$TERM" =~ 'screen' ]] && [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
  fucker=$(tmux list-panes -t $TMUX_MAN_PANE 2>&1)
  if ! [[ -z "$TMUX_MAN_PANE" ]] && ! [[ $fucker =~ 'find pane' ]]; then
    tmux -q respawn-pane -k -t $TMUX_MAN_PANE man $1
  else
    tmux split-window -vf man $1
    TMUX_MAN_PANE=$(tmux display-message -p "#{pane_id}")
    export TMUX_MAN_PANE
    tmux select-pane -t {last}
  fi
fi
}

tmux_man_page_close() {
  if [ $TMUX_MAN_PANE ]; then
     tmux kill-pane -t $TMUX_MAN_PANE
  fi
}
```

Comment: Your update does not include enough information.  Please (a) include  the values of `TERM`, `TMUX`, and `TMUX_MAN_PANE` from before the function runs and (b) include the output of the function and then (c) explain how that output differs from what you expect.

Comment: It's all a mess. In the first line of the if statement, I just want to know if that command is throwing an error. There is no seemingly rational way to do that. I don't want the output from the command, I want to know if it's throwing an error. That's it.

Comment: It's showing the command was a success even though it can't find the pane. I see no way to extract the output from that tmux command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is that `0` means true and `1` (or any other non-zero value) means false.

In shell, a test that is true (or a program which completes successfully), exits with code 0.  The test `[[ -z "$VAR" ]]` returns code zero (true) if `$VAR` is empty or one (false) if it is not empty:

```
$ var=""; [[ -z "$var" ]]; echo $?
0
$ var="NOT EMPTY"; [[ -z "$var" ]]; echo $?
1
```

In sum, if `$VAR` is non-empty, then `[[ -z "$VAR" ]]` is false (returns `1`) and the `then` statement does not execute.

Did you intend for the test to return true if the variable was non-empty?  If so, replace `-z` with `-n`:

```
$ var=""; [[ -n "$var" ]]; echo $?
1
$ var="NOT EMPTY"; [[ -n "$var" ]]; echo $?
0
```

For brevity, the same test is performed if `-n` is omitted:

```
$ var=""; [[ "$var" ]]; echo $?
1
$ var="NOT EMPTY"; [[ "$var" ]]; echo $?
0
```